# Exit app dialog from a fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I would like to prompt users to exit the app using the on back pressed, However I am struggling to implement this in my fragment

```js
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Really Exit?")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        HomeFragment.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                }).create().show();
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't think you can override onBackPressed() from a fragment, you need to do that from the activity that holds the fragment

Comment: You can add NegativeButton (Cancel) on dialog, So when user click on cancel button then you can dismiss dialog.

Comment: You can't use onBackPressed() inside a Fragment

Comment: @has19 that will be the main activity then that holds my fragments, will try the code in there

Comment: Perfect, i used the code inside my activity which holds the fragment and is working perfect on all 3 of my fragments that i wanted this to work on!
@has19 if you put this as an answer i can accept it thank you

Comment: @james gd to hear ,just accept any one :) ,thx anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that inside Fragments, but it's possible in your situation as every fragment runs on some Activity.

Just put that onBackPressed code on the activity which contains fragment.

Answer (score 1):

use this code for showing alert dialog box

```
   final android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alertDialog.setTitle("Your text");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Your custom text")
                .setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Rate Us", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                //your custom toast 
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.cancel();
            }
        }).create().show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way and check if it works :

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    PUT YOUR CODE HERE
}
```